# java.util.Date special date 1980-04-06: wrong hour

Tags: java, java.util.date, java-17

We faced following problem:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", java.util.Locale.GERMAN);
    String dateInString = "06-04-1980";
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
```

before: Sun Apr 06 00:00:00 CEST 1980

after: Sun Apr 06 01:00:00 CEST 1980

Another example:

```
Date date = Date.from(LocalDate.of(1980, 4, 6).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Facing the same problem.

We thought change of java11 to java17 is the problem, but it wasn't. It was the change of the timezone from Europe/Berlin to Europe Vienna. On 1980-04-06 the daylight saving time was established in Austria and the change of the hour was at 00:00. So there was no 00:00 at this date.

Reproduceable example - changing timezone to "Europe/Berlin" results in 0 hour.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    for (LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(1500, 04, 01); date.isBefore(LocalDate.of(9999, 1, 1)); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
        Date out = Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Europe/Vienna")).toInstant());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Vienna")));
        cal.setTime(out);
        if (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 0) {
            System.out.println(date.format(formatter) + " > " + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("done");
```

All dates before 1893-03-31 have 23 as hour in timezone "Europe/Vienna", in "Europe/Berlin" its also 0.

Comment: What if you use `LocalDate`/the `java.time` API instead?

Comment: And what is the question now? What do you think is the right answer and why? What do you want to happen and why?

Comment: The question is why this happens and if there is a possibility to get correct date (with hour 0)

Comment: I think you misunderstood `java.util.Date` - it does not have an "hour". It represents an instant in time. The "hour" you see depends on how you print it out.

Comment: I know java.util.Date well. But if the representation of instant has the wrong value after parsing, there is something wrong. Especially when java 11 does it - imho - correct.

Comment: No, I would say that the java 11 output is even more wrong. "Sun Apr 06 00:00:00 CEST 1980" doesn't even represent the same instant as "1980-04-06T00:00:00+01:00". The latter appears to be the instant that you are trying to represent? Actually, *which instant are you trying to represent?* It would be very helpful if you can tell me the date, time, and timezone in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), or the number of seconds since unix epoch.

Comment: If java 17 output is more correct it would be great if there is an explanation what the change was and why. Because this date differs from old ones in our database - so old dates could not be found. And why is there only a problem with THIS date? Other dates do NOT have this "offset".

For example: 1980-04-07 has hour 0.

Comment: Don't quite understand your setup -  [mcve] please, demonstrating the _Because this date differs from old ones in our database - so old dates could not be found_

Comment: I added an example - please try if it is reproducible on your side.

Comment: Summer time began at 02:00 (AM) on that day, so the time 00:00 did exist. Also on my Java 18 I get `Sun Apr 06 00:00:00 CET 1980` (same as on your Java 11). What goes wrong on your Java 17 I can't tell.

Comment: There was a german law which said 0:00. https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Dokumente/BgblPdf/1979_490_0/1979_490_0.pdf, it says: "In the 1980 calendar year, daylight saving time begins on Sunday, April 6, 1980 at 00:00 and ends on Saturday September 27, 1980 24:00."


I tried in java 17 and java 11 facing problems mentioned above.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that law is for Austria, not Germany...? "Österreich" means Austria, right?

Comment: Correct, @Sweeper, “die Republik Österreich” refers to Austria, not Germany. And indeed `LocalDate.of(1980, Month.APRIL, 6).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Europe/Vienna"))` returns `1980-04-06T01:00+02:00[Europe/Vienna]`, so not 00:00. Seen on Java 11. Voting to close as “Not reproducible or was caused by a typo”.

Comment: Thank you for the complete and reproducible example using Austrian time (not German). My results on Java 11 and Java 17 are the same: Up to year 1893 I get hour 23 for a lot of dates (could easily be a bug in the old `GregorianCalendar` class). And then I finally get `06.04.1980 > 1`, so hour 1 for the date you mentioned from the outset.

Comment: Sorrym of course Austrian law. My fault. Any ideas for this strange behaviour?

Comment: A guess, by mistake you have your Java 11 use Europe/Berlin time zone as its default and your Java 17 use Europe/Vienna. As I said, I have not been able to reproduce. Also if you are using Europe/Vienna, then as I read the error was on Java 11, so if you move on to Java 17, it's gone and the problem is solved, is this correct?

Comment: @Ole V.V. thats not correct. Java 11 does is right, Java 17 I faced this problem...

Comment: Now I am completely confused. You say that in Austria summer time was introduced at midnight on 6 April 1980. This would mean that that day began at 01:00 (not 00:00). You say that Java 11 gave `Sun Apr 06 00:00:00 CEST 1980` and that this is correct?? And that Java 17 gave `Sun Apr 06 01:00:00 CEST 1980` and this is incorrect?? Could you please rewrite your question to clarify? Until then upholding my close vote.

Comment: For me a Date would be correct with 00:00 Time if not specified. Somehow it changed at special dates (e.g. 1980-04-06) and so there is a problem regarding old dates in database - so it would be "correct" for me, if there is always a 00:00 time component. I don't know exactly, if the summer time on 1980-04-06 was changed at midnight or not - that's only one thing I found out about this. The problem is the change of the Date - so old ones could not be found any more, therefore it would be "correct" for me with 00:00.

Comment: I tried other ZoneId now -> Berlin or Paris does not have this issues. Only facing it using Vienna.

Comment: I checked in Java 11 - there is Europe/Berlin set as default! So that's the problem. Thanks @Ole V.V.

Comment: Glad you found out! I wonder whether this question will be useful for future readers, or it’s better that you delete it? You have a delete link under it. If all your database dates have time 00:00, then maybe you should rather store them without time and retrieve them into `LocalDate` in Java. If you can’t change the database, then into `LocalDateTime`. Here *local* means without time zone, so `LocalDateTime` is guaranteed not to make any trouble over summer time no matter which time zone is your default.

Comment: I will edit it, so that others can find it regarding time zones. Information is useful for others facing same problem in Austria.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I still cannot reproduce exactly. Running your coide in Europe/Berlin time zone I get `Sun Apr 06 00:00:00 CET 1980`, not CEST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really a problem, it's a special thing about timezone "Europe/Vienna" which was changed in our system. If you get this problem, check your timezone, maybe it was changed by some other properties.

While summer time (DST) started at 02:00 o’clock in Germany on that date, it started already at midnight in Austria (Europe/Vienna time zone), so the time 00:00 did not exist, which is why we suddenly got 01:00. Both time zones are printed as CEST (Central European Summer Time), so the abbreviation does not allow us to distinguish.

Comment: The reason saving time adjustments usually take place at 2:00 is to move the odd behaviour off the day boundary. I'm surprised that lesson wasn't learned before 1980!

Answer (score 0):

I am in Israel, so in order to simulate the time zone of central Europe (using Java 17), I set the [System] property *user.timezone* to CET using the `-D` option of the [java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html) command. Then I ran the following code:

```java
/*
 * import java.time.ZoneId;
 * import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
 * import java.util.Date;
 */
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(1980, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(Date.from(zdt.toInstant()));
```

The result I got was:

```
Sun Apr 06 00:00:00 CET 1980
```

This is the result that you want, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the result I want, but if I run your code I get: Sun Apr 06 01:00:00 CEST 1980

Comment: @anm note `CET` in @Abra output - you are "expecting" `CEST`, however I always getting `Sun Apr 06 01:00:00 CEST 1980` regardless java version.

Comment: I tried same Code in different Java Versions and get differences. I recognized CET/CEST.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov When I call `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` it does not contain _CEST_ but it does contain _CET_.

Comment: I think the Java versions I've used have translated CET to Europe/Paris (not completely sure). Not really helpful for a problem with either Austria or Germany time zone.